# How to add classes to every menu block placed within in a specific region?

Tags: 8, theming

How do I add classes to menus but only when they appear within a certain region? Is there a way to do this in a theme?

Comment: Why would you need to? That's kind of the whole reason CSS has the concept of child selection. Why would `.region-name .menu` not work for your purposes, for example?

Comment: Unless you're working with an explicit css frawmework (e.g. bootstrap/materialize) and you're trying to add column classes I guess

Comment: I am working with bootstrap, I also have multiple style sheets that use the same class names but have different css for those same class name. it

Comment: Doing this allows for a different thing depending on where you are in the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can augment the variables collection available to any twig file by tweaking the appropriate preprocess ... for example ... if you create the following function within your $THEME$.theme file:

```
function $THEME$_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $block_id = $variables['elements']['#id'];
  $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id);
  $variables['region'] = $block->getRegion();
}
```

you can then access the newly defined **region** variable from within:

```
{{ region }}
```

you could then add your desired classes to menus but only when they appear within a certain regions:

```
{% set classes = 'menu' ~ ((region == 'header') ? ' menu-header') %}
{% block content %}
    <nav {{ content_attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {{ content }}
    </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

that would add the class **menu** to all blocks and additionally would add the class **menu-header** to any block within the header region

hope that helps!